# Passing an instance of a Class with methods to a function PHP

Tags: php

I am struggling with some PHP code here. Like the title says, I am trying to pass an instance of a Class as a parameter to a function (Note, this file is in another file and has a different scope, and thus I need to pass it as a parameter). 
This is the code I have currently set up:

```
  // requires built this page, the classes and the functions are in seperate files. 
  // That's why I need to pass it in as a parameter.

  class ClassName {
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function getAge(){
      return $this->age;
    }
  } $className = new ClassName();

  // seperate file
  var_dump($className); // works, but has no methods.

  function randomFunc($className){
      echo $className->getAge(); // call to undefined method className::getAge()
  } randomFunc($className);
```

EDIT 2:
I have uploaded my code here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99954d61ca4d3f53ce549dab9f8333630633d89c

I hope you people can help me, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you include the file with the class definition in the separate file?

Comment: That is correct! @CharlotteDunois

Comment: `var_dump` does not show methods, also with `echo` you don't see if there is no output or just no data to show. Yo didn't set an age in your class, so `getAge` returns NULL, which can't be displayed by `echo`. Do for test purposes `private $age = 12;` (or any other number) and it will work.

Comment: You have to understand that this is an example based upon the problem I am facing. The current code is much more complex, but it fails on the same thing. You were correct on the $age, a small error I made while replicating this example. So this should work?

Comment: `var_dump` `$className` in your function and see what you pass to it. It should work.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Updated my question with a link to my current code. Well, the relevant parts.

Comment: There is **no** `processQuery` method in your class. You probably meant to use `handleQuery`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Ahh, this is painful. I just completely did not notice that. Well, I earn you a huge thanks. So here it comes, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
<?php
class ClassName {
    private $name;
    private $age = 19;

    public function getAge(){
      return $this->age;
    }
  } 

  function randomFunc($className){
      echo $className->getAge(); // call to undefined method className::getAge()
  } 

$className = new ClassName();

randomFunc($className);
```

Outputs: 19

Your code also runs fine for me, it just outputs nothing since $age is empty.

What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I am using PHP 5/7 on XAMPP. You have to understand that this is an example based upon the problem I am facing. The current code is much more complex, but it fails on the same thing. You were correct on the $age, a small error I made while replicating this example. So in theory, this is not wrong?

Comment: I already got my answer, I made a silly mistake. Thank you very much anyway for providing such a nice answer!